# How to keep dynamic radio button checked when get data from server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of radio button which is dynamically generated from PHP script also I have function in it . when I check a radio button the data passes from the radio button to a PHP file by JQuery AJAX post and get a value and I refresh the page to see the effect but the problem is when it is refreshed the radio button got unchecked. I want to keep the radio button checked by getting their value.

This is the PHP Code .

```
<?php   
while($metals = $showr->fetch_array()) {
    ?>

    <input type="radio" name="metal" onclick="getDesign()" <?php if(isset($metal) && ($metal) == '5') echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> id="metal" value="<?php echo $metals['code']; ?>"><?php echo $metals['metal']; ?>

    <?php }

<script type="text/javascript">
function getDesign() {
var radioValue = $("input[name='metal']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>image_filter.php",
    data:{metal: radioValue, id: <?php echo $id; ?>},
    success: function(data){
        $("input[name='metal']:checked").prop('checked', true);
        location.reload();
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me how can I keep a radio button checked when changes the radio button.

Comment: Why are you reloading the page since ajax can help you update elements without page reload?

Comment: you have need to send the checked info with window reload, and on based on that make radio button checked.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update this value in database : radioValue, with radio button id

Once page reloaded it should auto checked.